# Updating multiple MYSQL rows with one submit button

Tags: php, mysql, loops, form-submit

i was trying to updating multiple MYSQL rows with one submit button,

before i used to create submit for each row, but since i have a lot of rows now i need to update them all together

index.php

```
<?php
if (mysqli_num_rows($row){
while($row1= mysqli_fetch_assoc($row){


id<input  type="text" value="<?php echo $row["id"];?>"  name='id' id="id"  >
id<input  type="text" value="<?php echo $row["name"];?>"  name='name' id="name"  >
}
<button type="submit" formaction="update.php">
         submit
      </button>

}
```

update.php

```
$id= $_POST['id'];
$name= $_POST['name'];

$sql = "UPDATE `$tabelname` SET  
name='$name' 
WHERE id='$id'";
```

its updating the first row only

Comment: I find it a bit hard to believe that your code runs with `if (mysqli_num_rows($row)` which will cause a parse error. Is that your actual code or did you accidentally miss the missing bracket? Same for `while($row1= mysqli_fetch_assoc($row)`.

Comment: Plus this `while($row1` < you're using `$row1` but not using it. You used `$row`. Plus where and how is `$tabelname` defined?

Comment: Then you have `id<input` which that will also cause another error, being an undefined constant notice. Your question is unclear.

Comment: this is not the actual code. everything is working fine on my end, >> when i click update i want to use the same one button to update all the row together

Comment: so the update.php is taking the first row and update it successfully and then stop, but i want it to update all the rows from index.php not only the first one

Comment: You have the same names for your inputs on every row. There's only one `$_POST['id']`, it will be from the last row.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `id` is the primary key,

In your html, you need to use an array in the name. This allows the form to send it as an array instead of just taking the last value:

```
<?php while($row1= mysqli_fetch_assoc($row): ?>
    <div>
        <label>Name: </label>
        <input type="text" value="<?=$row["name"]?>"  name="name[<?= $row["id"] ?>]" id="name-"<?= $row["id"] ?> " />
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The key here is name=“name[]”. The square brackets make it an array. I’m using the id as the index. (Note that `<?=` is just a much more concise way of writing `<?php echo`)

Then, in your php script, the easiest way to show you is to iterate through the array and do an update each time:

```
$row = $_POST[‘name’];
foreach($row as $id => $name) {
    // This is a big No-No!
    // $sql = "UPDATE `$tabelname` SET name='$name' WHERE id='$id'";

    // use prepared statements. Always. 
    $sql = "UPDATE `$tabelname` SET name=? WHERE id=?"; // assuming “tabelname” is not user-provided

    // database connection up to you
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute( [$name, $id] );
}
```